# How do i configure CD Servers by removing unwanted config entries?

Tags: site-configuration

Once we are ready with CM server when deploying the files to CD server,what are all the config changes i should make?

For example shell site(CM related) is not required in CD. Is there a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. Several, in fact. It depends on your Sitecore version.

You should read through the official guide: [Configure a content delivery server](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server)

It describes things you need to consider, depending on your particular setup. It also describes any inline edits you should make to existing config files.

Additionally, again depending on your setup, there are a number of config files you can toggle off on a CD server.

- For Sitecore 8.2, download the [Config Enable Disable Excel spreadsheet for Sitecore 8.2 initial release.](https://doc.sitecore.net//~/media/E81335534D694F7997DA3BB9882CBBDB.ashx?la=en)
- For Sitecore 8.2 Update 1, download the [Config Enable Disable Excel spreadsheet for Sitecore 8.2 Update 1.](https://doc.sitecore.net//~/media/2D2D26345F5D41EA8D35B7965F3B914E.ashx?la=en)
- For Sitecore 8.2 Update 2, download the [Config Enable Disable Excel spreadsheet for Sitecore 8.2 Update 2.](https://doc.sitecore.net//~/media/0E14F3842E1A411B9811DB17B695B7B2.ashx?la=en)

I've not seen a version for 8.2 Update 3, as of yet.

Using Windows PowerShell, there is also a script available that can help. For more information, see: [Sitecore 8: Toggle CD Configuration Files Powershell Script](http://sitecoreunleashed.blogspot.ch/2015/09/sitecore-8-toggle-cd-configuration.html).

Comment: A small correction: the PowerShell script is for Windows PowerShell, not for SPE.

Comment: My bad. Corrected :-)